# Community Thank you?

Tags: discussion

I just went and looked at the number of votes I had on the Torture question.  I am both amazed and humbled.  I was just wondering.  Is there any sort of mechanism to offer the community some sort of "thank you" for all the votes on that answer?  Sorry to be such a noob on Meta, but I figure it's a good place to ask these sort of silly questions.

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Comment: I think having such a great answer on the site is our true reward. Well done; keep it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got it backwards: **it's us who thanked you, through upvotes.**

That question is of high quality, so much so that it was [tweeted by the CEO](http://twitter.com/#!/spolsky/status/80285285954502656) and [featured in the Stack Overflow blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/). Upvotes is how we reward high quality content. [Each vote in an implicit thank you.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/) In this case, it's quite clear we are appreciative. Keep up the good work Larian.

Answer (score 2):

You've just done it. :)

Keep up the very high quality answers Mr LeQ! I know I'm not the only one that appreciates them. It's great to see some level-headed passion on these here pages.

Comment: _\*twitch\*_... the images... always with the images with you people...

Comment: The case of the unprofessional entertainment image. I'm sorry - but -1. See here: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/818/what-is-the-criteria-for-an-unacceptable-image/834#834

Answer (score 1):

Steve, your passion is what inspired me to join this community.  Normally I tend just to stay on the sidelines, but I think that anyone that is as pssionate as you is a good spokesperson for skepticism.  Even if your fruit salad is less impressive than mine now!  ;)